# No inserta formulario en la Base de Datos

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Estoy realizando un sistema de inventario con PHP Y SQL SERVER 2008, al realizar la conexión es exitosa pero al insertar datos y consultarlos en la base de datos verifico y no inserta nada.

```
 $serverName = ("10.21.22.235"); //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (por defecto es 1433
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"new", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"");
    $conexion = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    //include('conexion.php');




    if($conexion===false)
    {
        die(print_r (sqlsrv_errors(),true));

    }

    if ($_POST)

   {
      $id_area_mant=$_POST['id_area_mant'];
      $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
      $ap=$_POST['ap'];
      $am=$_POST['am'];
      $contra=$_POST['contra'];


      $tsql= "INSERT into 'Area'(id_area_mant,nombre,ap,am,contra) 
      values ('$id_area_mant','$nombre','$ap','$am','$contra')";

   $recurso=sqlsrv_query($conexion,$tsql);

   if($recurso)
   {
   echo"Agregado correctamente";
   }
   else
   {
   echo"No Agregado";
   }

   }

?>
```

Comment: Para empezar, esto es erróneo: `$tsql= "INSERT into 'Area'(id_area_mant,nombre,ap,am,contra) 
      values ('$id_area_mant','$nombre','$ap','$am','$contra')";`, no tienes que poner comillas a las variables $. Entonces: `$tsql= "INSERT into Area (id_area_mant,nombre,ap,am,contra) 
      values ('.$id_area_mant.','.$nombre.','.... .')'";` Eso es lo de menos, **el error más grave es que tu código es presa fácil de inyección SQL** nunca mandes una consulta así a la BD: http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php Usa PDO bien configurado, es la mejor opción.

Comment: Previamente esta configurado el PDO y ya se modifico lo que sugieres y sigue el mismo problema.

Comment: Con PDO tu INSERT sería algo así más o menos: **`$sentencia = $mbd->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$sentencia->bindParam(':name', $nombre);
$sentencia->bindParam(':value', $valor);`** Ver el manual de PHP: http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Sale algo en los logs de PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes errores en los valores:

```
('$id_area_mant','$nombre,'$ap',$am,$contra)
```

Intenta cambiarlos por:

```
('$id_area_mant','$nombre','$ap','$am','$contra')
```

Comment: Tienes razón faltaron comillas, pero el el problema continua corrigiendo la sintaxis.

Answer (score 0):

Quítale las comillas al nombre de la tabla. En vez de:

```
$tsql= "INSERT into 'Area' (...
```

Debes escribir:

```
$tsql= "INSERT into Area (...
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías obtener los errores para saber qué es lo que está fallando. Es difícil encontarlo a ciegas.

```
if( $recurso === false ) {
if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
    foreach( $errors as $error ) {
        echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
        echo "codigo: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
        echo "mensaje: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque es una pregunta antigua y tiene respuestas parciales válidas, pondré el resumen de todas ellas, que es tan sencillo como poner el nombre de la tabla (`Area`) sin comillas y poner comillas simples alrededor de los parámetros.

```
$tsql= "INSERT into Area (id_area_mant, nombre, ap, am, contra) 
values ('$id_area_mant','$nombre','$ap','$am','$contra')";
```

Aunque tal como comenta A.Cedano, la forma adecuada y segura de hacer esta operación sea utilizando parámetros con [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php), evitando la [inyección de sql](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Answer (score -1):

pienso que la consulta que usas para insertar los datos tiene errores en la sintaxis, probaste corriendo la consulta que genera tu script directamente en sql, por ejemplo te flata una comilla que cierre cuando pasas el valor contenido en $nombre

```
$tsql= "INSERT into 'Area'(id_area_mant,nombre,ap,am,contra) 
  values ('$id_area_mant','$nombre','$ap',$am,$contra)";
```

Comment: Buenas tardes. Estoy utilizando SQL SERVER 2008 y tienes razón faltan comillas.

Comment: tu campo id_area_mant es tipo cadena?? pregunto porque por lo regular estos campos son de tipo entero, si es el caso y tu campo es entero necesitas quitar las comillas de ese campo